# Error Using RockMelt Browser

Tags: dns, nameserver

When visiting my [website](http://www.animefushigi.com) using a browser called **RockMelt** I get the following error:

`requested range is not satisfiable`

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Does your website work in other browsers? (Chrome, Firefox, etc.)

If so, RockMelt is likely at fault.

Comment: Yes it's fine in other browsers

Comment: The error is caused when the browser makes a request to the server for more data than is actually available.